# In Spacemacs, how can I append files to the current buffer on org-export?

Tags: include, export, org-mode, spacemacs

I believe org-mode in emacs uses  #+INCLUDE: ~/file
but I have not used emacs prior to trying Spacemacs.

Answer (score 0):

Got this answered on Spacemacs Gitter:
It's just necessary to add the lines to the body text of the parent file (in this case 3.org) like so:

---

- File 3

---

### #+INCLUDE: "~/test/2.org" export org

### #+INCLUDE: "~/test/1.org" export org

Then use org-export-to-org and the files 2.org and 1.org will be appended to 3.org (or added within the body at the point the INCLUDE line was placed) in the output: 3.org.org